# What's the formula behind Normalization function?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, scikit-learn

**sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer(norm=l2)**

I need to undone a normalization (**Normalizer algorithm**) within my dataset and I'd like to know which formula I should use for it. I've try both formulas (below) and didn't work out.

- z-score formula: $X_{original} = (x_{normalized} \cdot \sigma) + \mu$
- Min-Max formula: $X_{original} =  [x_{normalized} \cdot (X_{max} - X_{min})] + X_{min}$

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html)

> Each sample (i.e. each row of the data matrix) with at least one non zero component is rescaled independently of other samples so that its norm (l1, l2 or inf) equals one.

So if $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_p)$ is a row of the data matrix, the normalizer changes it to $(x_1 / \|x\|_2, \ldots, x_p/\|x\|_2)$, where $\|x\|_2 := \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_p^2}$.

If using `norm='l1'`, then $\|x\|_2$ is replaced by $\|x\|_1 = |x_1| + \cdots + |x_p|$; if using `norm='inf'`, then $\|x\|_2$ is replaced by $\|x\|_\infty := \max\{|x_1|, \ldots, |x_p|\}$.